# IP with C in the end (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxC)

Tags: ip, openvpn

I have a OpenVPN Server where a lot of diffrent machine are connecting to it and getting their own IP. Thus, we can access any machine from the server. Until now everything worked fine. But now we have some machines which have a C behind the IP (e.g. 10.111.8.1C).  We can no longer connect to these machines. Does anyone have an idea what this C stands for? I could not find anahltspunkt on the Internet.